# How to increment the data-target value in php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, sass

[image]Hello I am trying to create a 3 tab block for my wordpress site.  When the user clicks on tab 1 they will get tab 1 content, when they click on tab 2 they will get tab 2 content and so forth.  My problem is I do not know how to increment the data target value.  Since its all three tabs have a target value of "tab-1" it will not correspond with the CSS.  The other content will not stay hidden.  Also, I do not want my active class to be looped as well, I only want the yellow active css class to be present on the first tab. Thank you

```css
//=====Tab Row CSS=======
.nav-tabs li::before {
    content: ''!important;
}
.nav-tabs {
/*  display: flex; */
/*  padding: 0 100px 0; */
/*  background-color: #2f1400; */
    border-bottom: 2px solid $color-text;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .nav-tabs .nav-item {
        max-width: 233px;
    }
    .nav-tabs {
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
}
.nav-tabs li a.active,
.nav-tabs li:hover a{
    background-color: $color-gold !important;
    color: $color-text !important;
}
.nav-tabs li a{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid $color-text !important;
/*  border-radius: 0 !important; */
    color: $color-text;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.nav-content {
    max-width: 1200px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .nav-tabs li a{ 
    border-radius: 0 !important;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    .nav-tabs li {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
<?php
    $tabs = get_field('tab' );
    if( $tabs ) :
        foreach( $tabs as $tab) :
        $headline = $tab['headline'];
        ?>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-1"
    type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true"><?php echo $headline; ?></a>
  </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content page" id="myTabContent">
<?php
    $tabs = get_field('tab' );
    if( $tabs ) :
        foreach( $tabs as $tab) :
        $description = $tab['description'];
        ?>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-1">
  <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  

 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable at the number you want to start, like 1, and then utilize [PHP's post-increment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) `$a++` to increase its value while you're in the loop for the next tab or content.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <?php
    $tabIndex = 1;
    $tabs = get_field('tab');
    if( $tabs ) :
        foreach( $tabs as $tab) :
        $headline = $tab['headline'];
        ?>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link<?php if ($tabIndex === 1) { echo ' active'; } ?>" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-<?php echo $tabIndex; ?>" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
        <?php echo $headline; ?>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php $tabIndex++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content page" id="myTabContent">
  <?php
    $tabIndex = 1;
    $tabs = get_field('tab');
    if( $tabs ) :
        foreach( $tabs as $tab) :
        $description = $tab['description'];
        ?>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show<?php if ($tabIndex === 1) { echo ' active'; } ?>" id="tab-<?php echo $tabIndex; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-<?php echo $tabIndex; ?>">
      <p>
        <?php echo $description; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <?php $tabIndex++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much wouch. I will study your answer. At first this solution was not working but, i removed the "active" off of "nav-link active". And then i removed the "show active" off of "tab-pane fade show active". It works if i do this but is there way I can make the first <li> active without making the others active.  So the first tab shows when the user lands on the page? Would this be pure CSS, like a nth child sort of thing?

Comment: You're welcome! You can add a conditional check in the `PHP` to check if the loop is on the first element and if so then echo an 'active' class. Then use CSS to show/hide how you wish utilizing that class. I updated the snippet to show how I mean.

Comment: That worked, Thank you again for your time. I'm gonna study up on my PHP.